# How to change the fd associated with the stdin file descriptor?

Tags: linux, ipc

I want to associate pipe's write fd to the stdout.

```
int pfds[2];
char buf[30];

if (pipe(pfds) == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
}

I want to associate pfd[1] to the stdout of the process.
```

I understand, we can use freopen to redirect stdout to the file. I was hoping to get something similar to this.

Comment: why not `pfd[1] = stdout`, then?

Answer (score 3):

[`dup2(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) is probably the easiest way:

```
dup2(pfds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Comment: And you very likely want to close the original pipe descriptor, close(pfds[1])

Comment: Yup; that's possible.