# What does dup2() do in C

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor, dup2

I looked it up in the man page but I still don't get it...

let's say you have `dup2(f1,0)`. Does that switch filedesc.1 with stdin and then locks stdin?

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Comment: Unix, pipes, my apologies

Comment: "dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary"

Comment: `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the fd associated with the stdin file descriptor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497401/how-to-change-the-fd-associated-with-the-stdin-file-descriptor)

Comment: Here's more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or

Comment: @staticx Your proposed duplicate doesn't explain anything. While there may well be a duplicate among all the questions that mention `dup2`, this isn't it.

Comment: @Gilles: I posted a second link, can't take back my proposed duplicate now

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`dup2` doesn't switch the file descriptors, it makes them equivalent. After `dup2(f1, 0)`, whatever file was opened on descriptor `f1` is now also opened (with the same mode and position) on descriptor 0, i.e. on standard input.

If the target file descriptor (here, 0) was open, it is closed by the `dup2` call. Thus:

```
before                         after
0: closed, f1: somefile        0: somefile, f1:somefile
0: otherfile, f1: somefile     0: somefile, f1:somefile
```

No locking is involved.

`dup2` is useful (among other things) when you have part of a program that reads or write from the standard file descriptors. For example, suppose that `somefunc()` reads from standard input, but you want it to read from a different file from where the rest of the program is getting its standard input. Then you can do (error checking omitted):

```
int save_stdin = dup(0);
int somefunc_input_fd = open("input-for-somefunc.data", O_RDONLY);
dup2(somefunc_input_fd, 0);
/* Now the original stdin is open on save_stdin, and input-for-somefunc.data on both somefunc_input_fd and 0. */
somefunc();
close(somefunc_input_fd);
dup2(save_stdin, 0);
close(save_stdin);
```

Comment: thorough explanation, tnx